# Socket io 2.0.4 Cannot find module './utf8' (Heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I try to install and run a simple app with nodeJs socket io and heroku.When i run the app locally i get no errors but when i try to run the app on heroku i get the following error :

```
Error: Cannot find module './utf8'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:5:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/engine.io-parser/index.js:2:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
```

Ι navigated with heroku console inside node_modules/enine.io-parser/lib and the utf8.js file was missing.When i downgraded socket-io to version 1.7 the error disappeared.
Is there any solution on how to run socket-io 2.0.4 with Heroku?

Comment: Was there any solution to this?